# How to obfuscate UiAutomator code?

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard, android-uiautomator

I have a test project developed in UiAutomator, which is not specific for one app, i.e., I don't even have any application associated to my test. My main folder only has the AndroidManifest, my code is all in the test folder.

I want to make my code available but ofuscated. So I want to obtain an APK of my code obfuscated.

My build.gradle contains

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testProguardFiles('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
        debug{
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testProguardFiles('proguard-rules.pro')
            debuggable true
        }
    }
```

and proguard-rules.pro file is:

```
-keep public class * extends android.test.InstrumentationTestCase
-keep public class * extends junit.framework.TestCase
-keep public class * implements junit.framework.TestCase
-keep class android.support.** { *;}
-keep interface android.support.** { *;}
-keep public class junit.framework.** { *;}
-keep class android.uiautomator.** { *;}

-keep class com.impactToolTester.utility.Constants
-keepclasseswithmembernames class *{
    public <init>(java.lang.Class,android.support.test.internal.util.AndroidRunnerParams);
}

-dontnote android.support.test.internal.runner.listener.CoverageListener
-dontwarn android.test.**

-dontnote org.junit.**
-dontnote junit.runner.*
-dontnote junit.framework.*
-dontnote android.net.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**
```

When I run gradlew assembleAndroidTest the app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk is created in build/outputs/apk.

However, when I decompile the apk I realise it's not obfuscated at all. I know the proguard file is read because I started with several errors when I first run it.

I have the minifyEnabled in both debug and release because I'm not sure which is run with assembleAndroidTest.

I'm a real newbie when it comes to proguard and obfuscation in general so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how this works?